# django-mongodb : retrieve an object giving error(s)

Tags: django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I'm using the django_mongo_engine(0.4.0) as backed for django application.

an `Instructor` object is created using like

```
inst = Instructor.objects.create(
        email=request.POST.get('email').lower(),
        password = set_password(request.POST.get('password')),
        title=request.POST.get('title'),
        first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'),
        last_name=request.POST.get('last_name'))
```

and

```
request.session['inst_id'] = inst.id
```

in mongo shell this **inst.id** appears to be **ObjectId(u'533c3b0c9b0dbb416e000000')**

while in debug mode (pdb)

```
Instructor.objects.all()[0].id
```

will give **id** `u'533c3b0c9b0dbb416e000000'`

Error(s) when retrieving instructor object:

```
 Instructor.objects.get(id=request.session['inst_id'])
```

**ValueError:** invalid literal for int() with base 10: '533c40a99b0dbb42d9000000'

```
instructor2 = Instructor.objects.get(id=ObjectId(request.session['inst_id']))
```

**TypeError**: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ObjectId'

```
instructor3 = Instructor.objects.get(id=str(request.session['inst_id']))
```

**ValueError:** invalid literal for int() with base 10: '533c40a99b0dbb42d9000000'

Any clue ?